# how to save the entered text in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

i want to know how to save the entered text by user in a shiny app to use it in the server side.
i want to check if the value that the user has entered is valid or not
in the user side there is this textInput:

```
      textInput("entity1", "Enter a keyword")
```

and in the server side i want to check the value of the user using this code:

```
entity1 <- reactive({
if(input$actb >= 0 ){
  withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
    for(i in 1:15) {
      setProgress(message = 'please wait',detail = 'it may take some time',value=i)
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
  })}
smallE= "[a-z]"
keyword = as.character(input$entity1)
if(match(input$entity1, smallE))
{
  message("sorry you did not enter a valid keyword. please try again")
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
else
  entity1 <- readTweets()
```

})

I have tried to declare a global variable in the server side to save the input:

```
    if(match(as.vector(userInput), smallE))
```

userInput is a global variable contains the value of entity1

but there is a error that keep showing saying that:

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

any suggestions that may help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a validate function, such as in this example:

```
validate(
  need(input$searchTerm != "", "Please, enter the correct search term")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tease apart with just this chunk of code. I would avoid calling out any globals, however, you can assign NULL values until a user has specified input values.

You are also calling your object and your reactive functions both "entity1", so that is a little confusing.

One other thing is that you define the object "keyword" but then never use it again.

And I think you might do better using %in% as your binary rather than match().

Not sure if any of this helps...but the error you are seeing is specifically with the as.vector() part of your code.  I am not even sure why you are using that, as any string in the textInput field will come in as a vector already.